# Update the data in excel instead of deleting

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is deleting the records but I want to update the next column as "OK" instead of deleting entire row. Please advise as to what all changes are required.

```
Dim myFileNameDir As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim iRow1 As Long
Dim str As String


myFileNameDir = "C:\Users\GShaikh\Desktop\Book16.xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Students")


str = ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(1)

MsgBox str


    With ws1
      .AutoFilterMode = False
      iRow1 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

          With .Range("B1:D" & iRow1)
              .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & str & "*"
              .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
          End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this is not your `enter code here`site. Just try for yourself and ask when encountering problems.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to remove: (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

And replace it with something like Cells.Value = "OK"

Comment: Please provide me the code to put "OK" in very next column

Comment: Do I need to code as below .Offset(1, 0).value = "OK"

Comment: I usually don't use offset, but the first digit is for rows, the second for columns. So in this case you would need to change them over. And perhaps you need to increase the number 1 into something more. Just try and see what happens.

Comment: Does it work now? If you find my answer helpful I would appreciate it if you could accept it as the answer to your question by pressing the check mark left to my answer.